# JavaScript Dates and Times

Tags: javascript, phpjs

What is the JavaScript equivalent to the following PHP code:

```
$expTime = time() + (5 * 60 * 60); // now plus 5 hours (5 hour; 60 mins; 60 secs) 
$expTimeStr = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $expTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var expTime    = new Date((+new Date()) + (5 * 60 * 60000))
var m          = expTime.getMonth() + 1
var d          = expTime.getDate()
var y          = expTime.getFullYear()
var h          = expTime.getHours()
var i          = expTime.getMinutes()
var s          = expTime.getSeconds()
var expTimeStr = y +"-"+ m +"-"+ d +" "+ h +":"+ i +":"+ s
```

Comment: This isn't going to work.

If the time is 11:00PM, then the hour will be correct, but the day display will be wrong.

Comment: fixed bluntly using gnarfs method for the +5 hours

Comment: That's a nice solution! I changed something anyways: it's weird that you don't have a leading zero for Month, Day, Minutes and Seconds (even Hours). So, to whom might be interested: `var expTimeStr = y +"-"+ (m.toString().length<2 ? '0' : '')+m +"-"+ (d.toString().length<2 ? '0' : '')+d + ...`

Comment: Important!! If you want the right local time offset: `var expTime = new Date((+new Date()) + (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000))`

Answer (score 1):

The [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/gmdate) function doesn't transfer well to JavaScript...  There is a [`gmdate()` port on phpjs](http://phpjs.org/functions/gmdate:586) that uses the [`date()` function from phpjs](http://phpjs.org/functions/date:380) to do the complex formatting.

To calculate the date:

```
var time = new Date((+new Date()) + (5 * 60 * 60000)); // js times are ms

alert(time.toUTCString()); // quick JS method to return UTC time
```

The `(+new Date())` forces the Date() into an integer before adding ms, and passing it back to the `new Date()` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The built in date formatting for Javascript isn't incredible, but I can offer two helpful libraries to accomplish what you want.
The first is something called phpjs - Javascript ports of a number of php functions.

http://phpjs.org/functions/index

http://phpjs.org/functions/gmdate:586

The second is a jQuery plugin:

http://joncom.be/code/jquery-phpdate/